# How can I make the data inside of my Cart become persistent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, next.js, local-storage

I have a NextJS application that is using the ShopifyBuy SDK. I have been successfully able to implement a solution where I am able to fetch the products from Store and display them to the User. The user is also able to go to a product page and add the product to the cart.

However, when the user refreshes the page, the cart is reset, and the data does not persist. The code is below:

**context/cart.js:**

```
import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useReducer } from "react";
import client from "../lib/client";
import Cookies from "js-cookie";

const CartStateContext = createContext();
const CartDispatchContext = createContext();

const SET_CART = "SET_CART";

const initalState = {
  lineItems: [],
  totalPrice: 0,
  webUrl: "",
  id: "",
};

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_CART:
      return { ...state, ...action.payload };
    default:
      throw new Error(`Unknown action: ${action.type}`);
  }
};

export const CartProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const savedState = Cookies.get("cartState");
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, savedState || initalState);

  useEffect(() => {
    Cookies.set("cartState", state, { expires: 7 });
  }, [state]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getCart();
  }, []);

  const setCart = (payload) => dispatch({ type: SET_CART, payload });

  const getCart = async () => {
    try {
      const cart = await client.checkout.create();
      setCart(cart);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  return (
    <CartDispatchContext.Provider value={{ setCart }}>
      <CartStateContext.Provider value={{ state }}>
        {children}
      </CartStateContext.Provider>
    </CartDispatchContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useCartState = () => useContext(CartStateContext);
export const useCartDispatch = () => useContext(CartDispatchContext);
```

**products/[handle].tsx:**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import client from "../../lib/client";
import { useCartDispatch, useCartState } from "../../context/cart";
import Link from "next/link";
import cookie from "js-cookie";

export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  const res = await client.product.fetchAll();
  const paths = res.map((product: any) => {
    return {
      params: { handle: product.handle.toString() },
    };
  });

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false,
  };
};

export const getStaticProps = async (context: any) => {
  const handle = context.params.handle;
  const res = await client.product.fetchByHandle(handle);
  const product = JSON.stringify(res);
  return {
    props: {
      product,
    },
  };
};

function Product({ product }: any) {
  const { state } = useCartState();
  const { setCart } = useCartDispatch();

  const addToCart = async () => {
    const checkoutId = state.id;
    const lineItemsToAdd = [
      {
        variantId: product.variants[0].id,
        quantity: 1,
      },
    ];

    const res = await client.checkout.addLineItems(checkoutId, lineItemsToAdd);
    setCart(res);
  };

  product = JSON.parse(product);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className=" flex-col text-2xl font-bold m-8 flex items-center justify-center ">
        <h1>{product.title}</h1>
        <button onClick={addToCart}>Add to Cart</button>
        <Link href="/cart">Checkout</Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Product;
```

**pages/cart/index.tsx:**

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useCartState, useCartDispatch } from "../../context/cart";
import client from "../../lib/client";

function Cart() {
  const { state } = useCartState();

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Cart</h1>
      {state.lineItems &&
        state.lineItems.map((item: any) => {
          return (
            <div key={item.id}>
              <h2>{item.title}</h2>
              <p>{item.variant.title}</p>
              <p>{item.quantity}</p>
            </div>
          );
        })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Cart;
```

I have tried using a library called js-cookie and also localStorage. I'm not sure where the problem lies or if the solutions that I've tried are wrong.

P.S.: I'm fairly new to NextJS and Typescript so go easy on the syntax. This code is for a personal project. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Jordy! I pasted an answer, please give it a try and let me know.

Comment: @yousoumar thank you for the response. I have tried your solution and I get a "localStorage" is not defined error. I ran into this already and I believe it's due to the fact that local storage cannot be used with server-side components. That is why I was going down the route of cookies.

Comment: Hi Jordy! Check out my last edited answer. I forgot the next thing, where you need a check before using `localStorage`. Give it a try and let me know.

Comment: @yousoumar thanks again! I have a working solution right now so I’ll give yours a go and compare.

Comment: Hi Jordy! Did you give it a try?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want your server to know about the cart, you don't have to use cookies to store it. You could use `localStorage`, like so:

```
import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useReducer } from "react";
import client from "../lib/client";

const CartStateContext = createContext();
const CartDispatchContext = createContext();

const SET_CART = "SET_CART";

const initalState =
  typeof localStorage !== "undefined" && localStorage.getItem("cartState")
    ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cartState"))
    : {
        lineItems: [],
        totalPrice: 0,
        webUrl: "",
        id: "",
      };

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_CART:
      return { ...state, ...action.payload };
    default:
      throw new Error(`Unknown action: ${action.type}`);
  }
};

export const CartProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initalState);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.set("cartState", JSON.stringify(state));
  }, [state]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getCart();
  }, []);

  const setCart = (payload) => dispatch({ type: SET_CART, payload });

  const getCart = async () => {
    try {
      const cart = await client.checkout.create();
      setCart(cart);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  return (
    <CartDispatchContext.Provider value={{ setCart }}>
      <CartStateContext.Provider value={{ state }}>{children}</CartStateContext.Provider>
    </CartDispatchContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useCartState = () => useContext(CartStateContext);
export const useCartDispatch = () => useContext(CartDispatchContext);
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering this because I ended up coming up with a solution that works for me, at least.

Here it is:

```
  const getCart = async () => {
    try {
      const checkoutId = Cookies.get("checkoutId");
      let cart;
      if (checkoutId) {
        cart = await client.checkout.fetch(checkoutId);
      } else {
        cart = await client.checkout.create();
        Cookies.set("checkoutId", cart.id);
      }
      setCart(cart);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
```

From my understanding, what this does is the following:

1. Check the cookies to see if one exists called "checkoutId"
2. If it exists, fetch the cart using that checkoutId
3. Otherwise, create a new cart and create a cookie using the cart.id that is returned in the response

Then, inside my individual Product page ([handle].tsx), I'm doing the following:

```
const addToCart = async () => {
    const checkoutId = state.id;
    const lineItemsToAdd = [
      {
        variantId: product.variants[0].id,
        quantity: 1,
      },
    ];

    const res = await client.checkout.addLineItems(checkoutId, lineItemsToAdd);
    console.log(res);
    if (cookie.get("checkoutId") === undefined) {
      cookie.set("checkoutId", res.id);
    }
    setCart(res);
  };
```